# Problemas com float e position absolute

Tags: jquery, css, menu

olá, estou tentando fazer uma espécie de menu assim:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofjw7cah/1/

Porém, gostaria que o texto abrisse em largura 100% e ocupasse a linha toda. Como estou usando bootstrap, não consegui achar uma solução responsiva.

Comment: tem aqui algumas soluções http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Porque não utiliza o nav-tabs? Veja que simples.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Exemplo de Tabs</h2>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#capalivro1">Capa do Livro 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#capalivro2">Capa do Livro 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#capalivro3">Capa do Livro 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#capalivro4">Capa do Livro 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="capalivro1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Capa do Livro 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="capalivro2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Capa do Livro 2</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="capalivro3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Capa do Livro 3</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="capalivro4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Capa do Livro 4</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```